# Google in-app billing,Error retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I'm testing google's in-app billing. I follow the instruction of google in-app billing training, using the IabHelper.

I setup the IabHelper successfully.

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d("GooglePay", "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh no, there was a problem.
                Log.d("GooglePay", "Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(GooglePayPlugin.this);
            IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
            mActivity.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);
        }
    });
```

Then, I call the purchase API of IabHelper.

```
try {
     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mActivity, productID, RC_REQUEST,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
} catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
     Log.d("GooglePay", "Error launching purchase flow. Another async operation in progress.");
}
```

But, I always got a popup windows says: "从服务器检索信息时出错。[DF-DFERH-01]", as the following picture.
[image]

The logcat information is in attated.

Comment: logcat link:http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=654efa3f235e49e82023d7d11300ef13

Comment: what is `productID` in your code?

Comment: @rockstar I use the real product ID configured in google play store. I have double checked the Product ID is correct

Comment: I contact to the Google play online help. They told me I must download the app from the test link. I try the problem is the same

Comment: Yes, he is right.. you must download google play services into your phone.

Comment: Please check with your code with `android.test.purchased` product id

Comment: If this is working well then  problem in your product id, which are u created at Google store?

Comment: I got this error in logcat: E/Volley: [187] e.a: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/ees/acquire

Comment: @rockstar, I user the android.test.purchased product ID, then I got exactly the same problem....

Comment: can u update logcat error with ur question? please.

Comment: Ok. I will update some steps with my answer, please check with this and sure to covered all steps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue eventually, put my answer here, hope it help those who met the same problem like me.

mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mActivity, productID, RC_REQUEST,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

The "payLoad" parameter is too long, I set the payload to empty string, then the problem is sloved, no more df-dferh-01.

It's nothing to do with the VPN, nothing to do with the google library, just because the payload is too long for google play service interface.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with your code with following steps:

**STEP: 1**
check `sdk manager` with `sdk tool` is updated with `Google Play Billing Library` and `Google play services`

**STEP: 2**
Create an Android project and add billing permission to your Android project’s manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**STEP: 3**
 Adding the AIDL file to your project

> 1.By right click on you app-level folder>> Folder>> AIDL folder
>
> 2.Example for in app billing create directory or folder or package –> com.android.vending.billing
>
> 3.Then copy paste file in this package
>
> After doing all this you will get error in other InApp billing
>   supportive classes like IabHelper for importing that
>   InAppBillingService.aidl, to resolve it go to build.gradle and
>   readjust your directory for com.android.vending.billing which is not
>   correct format at the time of com.android.vending.billing directory or
>   package creation
>
> like:
>
> sourceSets { main { aidl.srcDirs = [‘src/main/aidl‘] } }

**STEP: 3**
Update dependencies in build.gradle file

**STEP: 4**
Initiate a Connection with Google Play

(Make sure **base64EncodedPublicKey** is right for your product)

(**Base64EncodedPublicKey** means `your license key from google play console`)

```
 /************Setting Up Google Play Billing in the Application***************/
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    // mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(@NonNull IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
                complain("In-app Billing setup failed:: " + result);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
            }
        }
    });
    /************Setting Up Google Play Billing in the Application***************/
```

**STEP: 5**

For testing purpose use following item_sku:

```
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;
```

in case of live use live `ProductID` which are you creating.

**STEP: 6**

1. Implementing `onActivityResult` Method for handling result

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
   {
   if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Implementing `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener`
3. Implementing `QueryInventoryFinishedListener`
4. Implementing `OnConsumeFinishedListener`

**STEP: 7**

make sure your device having updated `Google play services`

**STEP: 8**

calling the purchase API of IabHelper.

```
 mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mActivity, ITEM_SKU,
              RC_REQUEST,mPurchaseFinishedListener, mPayload);
```

**STEP: 9**
 For More please reference with following link:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-permission

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html#connecting

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I checked and tried these steps, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was setting wrong `SubscriptionUpdateParams`. If you use subscriptions, you probably have a code that sets `OldSkuPurchaseToken`. If you set wrong data there, you get this error.